# HTML and CSS - remove space between two divs

Tags: html, css

So i started to learn building a website a few days ago and sitting here trying to solve my problem - without success

**The HTML**

```
<div id="banner">
    <img src="Bilder/baustelle.jpg">
</div>

<div id="text">
    <p>Wir freuen uns über Ihren Auftrag!</p>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
#banner img{
    width: 100%;
}

#text{
    font-family: "Agency FB",sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
}

#text p{
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

My problem is the white gap between the text and the picture on the top.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: since you tagged as "php", I can only offer an educated guess as to why you have that extra space, in regards to a comment you posted below.

Comment: and a pending edit wants to remove the php tag from it http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15032982 which the tag is probably relevant to the problem here. You're not telling us the full story here.

Comment: well.... whatever; good luck with this.

Comment: Looks like i accidently removed a part of my question. Sorry for that, edited it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem, as identified in the other answers, is the top margin to the paragraph in the second div. Set that to 0.

The other problem is that the img in the fist div leaves room below for the descender. (In HTML, imgs behave like characters and they are vertically aligned to the baseline by default. So there's a couple of pixels of space below the image left.)

There are many solutions:

- In the style for #banner, include `font-size:0` so that the size of the descender becomes 0.

  ```css
      #banner {font-size:0}

      #banner img{
          width: 100%;
      }

      #text{
          font-family: "Agency FB",sans-serif;
          text-align: center;
          background: red;
      }

      #text p{
          margin-top:0;
          color: white;
          font-size: 50px;
      }
  ```

  ```html
      <div id="banner">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/100">
      </div>

      <div id="text">
          <p>Wir freuen uns über Ihren Auftrag!</p>
      </div>
  ```
- or align the image in the #banner to the top or to the bottom, rather than to the baseline. E.g. `#banner img {vertical-align:top}`

  ```css
      #banner img{
          width: 100%;
          vertical-align:top;
      }

      #text{
          font-family: "Agency FB",sans-serif;
          text-align: center;
          background: red;
      }

      #text p{
          margin-top:0;
          color: white;
          font-size: 50px;
      }
  ```

  ```html
      <div id="banner">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/100">
      </div>

      <div id="text">
          <p>Wir freuen uns über Ihren Auftrag!</p>
      </div>
  ```
- or turn the img into a block, so that it no longer behaves like a character. E.g. `#banner img {display:block}`

  ```css
      #banner img{
          width: 100%;
          display:block;
      }

      #text{
          font-family: "Agency FB",sans-serif;
          text-align: center;
          background: red;
      }

      #text p{
          margin-top:0;
          color: white;
          font-size: 50px;
      }
  ```

  ```html
      <div id="banner">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/100">
      </div>

      <div id="text">
          <p>Wir freuen uns über Ihren Auftrag!</p>
      </div>
  ```

Etc. I'm sure there are more.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting zero borders on all the elements.

```
#banner img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}

#text {
    font-family: "Agency FB",sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}

#text p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     #banner img{
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

    }

#text{
    font-family: "Agency FB",sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

#text p{
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast help! The gap isn´t removed away completely though: https://imgur.com/a/afKpB